# Responsive video resizing html/php

Tags: html, video, iframe, resize, responsive

I am currently trying to figure out a solution to resizing a video for a website I have created. This video is in a container which is responsive to a certain point but then stops resizing. This is annoying due to the fact i am forseeing most views of the website to be through mobile phones where the pixel resolution will be lower and a lot of the video will be cut off. Here is the website in question hosted on a free web host for now: [Website in question](https://zaksmithcomputing.000webhostapp.com/)

CSS:

```
.container{
  max-width:960px;
  padding-left:1rem;
  padding-right:1rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;

}    

.fullscreen-video-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:101%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}    

.fullscreen-video-wrap video{
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
}

@media(max-width:960px){
  .container{
    padding-right:3rem;
    padding-left:3rem;
  }
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: why is this a php question and where is the html for this?

Comment: Sorry but let me just tell you how to view the html for yourself. Click the link i provided, then right click the web page and view html... hope that helps :)

Comment: I will not visit your website to see what the HTML is and if this is php related, doing that won't do you or anyone else any good.

Comment: If you change `min-height` and `min-width` to just `height` and `width` video will be auto resizing

Comment: Thanks for the response, just tried that but with the same outcome. It seems the width stops resizing at a certain point, around 1200px

Comment: Edit: cleared my cache. You are correct the video is now resizing but it is not stretched to the correct aspect ratio and there are gaps eitherside of the video. Is there a way to maintain the aspect ratio so that it covers the whole screen/device whilst still resizing?

Comment: And how you want to do it? If you have setted height and only your width is changing your ratio will be changing too.

Comment: I would like it to change the aspect ratio based on the device that its playing on if possible. Would this be done through iframe?

Comment: But if you change aspect ratio your video will be cutted or deformed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182382/discussion-between-david-moskor-and-user3357649).